# Instantiate a TreeViewer before opening a dialog

Tags: dialog, swt, jface

I have a `TreeViewer` inside a `jface` `Dialog` window.
The `treeViewer` needs to be populated with a large number of items with the `setInput()`.And so it takes quite a bit of time for the `tree` to show, each time the dialog window is opened.

I want to know if there is any way to instantiate and save the `treeViewer` beforehand, so that the when the dialog window is opened, the `treeViewer` is just added to the dialog window and it is instantly visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall ever seeing anything try to do this. Creating the tree has to be done in the UI thread so this would still be difficult to do without stalling the UI.

There are various things you can do:

The model objects that the content provider provides can be built at any time since they are not UI objects. So you could get these in the background before the dialog is displayed.

You can use a virtual tree using the `SWT.VIRTUAL` style and an `ILazyTreeContentProvider` to delay building parts of the tree until they are needed.

If the code is in an Eclipse plugin you can use `org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager` to defer building parts of the tree (there isn't much documentation on this method).

Comment: The 2nd option is probably what I need. No need to build and show the whole tree from the beginning.